# Error instantiating Spring Configuration class from properties file when running in Docker container

Tags: java, spring-mvc, docker

I'm getting a NumberFormatException when I run my webapp in a Tomcat 8 Docker container. The error occurs when Spring tries to instantiate the MongoConfig class, which is injecting @Values taken from a classpath properties file. The properties in the properties file are as follows:

```
mongodb.host=mongodb
mongodb.database=mydatabase
mongodb.port=27017
mongodb.username=myusername
mongodb.password=mypassword
```

In the MongoConfig file it's falling over with a NumberFormatException when it gets to this point:

```
@Value("${mongodb.port}")
private int port;
```

According to the error, it's picking up "tcp://172.17.0.2:27017" as the input that it's trying to shoehorn into port, despite the fact that the properties file clearly gives the port without any other stuff like IP addresses. The IP address that it's picked up is what it's assigned to the mongodb container (a separate Docker container, no frills, just mongodb:latest with the --name mongodb, which is then --linked as mongodb:mongodb in the Tomcat container's run command). If you shell into the running Tomcat container & look at /etc/hosts you'll see the entry for mongodb, and it appears reachable from within the Tomcat container.

Why is Spring picking up the entire tcp address including IP and port, when it's been given the port on its own in the properties file? How should I deal with this?

Update - Error is: "Error creating bean with name 'com.mydomain.myproject.config.MongoConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'port': Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tcp://172.17.0.2:27017"; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [int]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tcp://172.17.0.2:27017""

It seems mongodb.port is being overridden within the container. Changing the port number to 99999 did nothing. Changing the property name to "mylovely.port" then gave us an error complaining that the port was out of range, & showed it to be 99999. Amending it back to 27017 then gave me a running webapp, no crashes. The question that remains is, what overrides this value & why does a property called port have a whole address? Is it that the --link option not only sets up an entry in the tomcat container's /etc/hosts but also creates some kind of global variable or property called mongodb which regardless of whatever comes after it always returns the full address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docker sets an environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#environment-variables) `MONGODB_PORT` that takes precedence over configuration file. You can prove it by inspecting (`docker inspect`) a container or, if it won't work, by using `docker exec` and executing `env` command within a container.

**UPDATED:**
How to solve it? First, [read about `PropertySource` abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer). Next, you will find out that environment variable value could be override by system property (`-Dmongodb.port=27017`). Also I'd try to [use `PropertyOverrideConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer) but I'm not sure that it will work thought.

Comment: Thanks Slava! I'll have a look at that. Good to know I'm not going nuts. :-)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not seeing that here.
This is what happens when I inspect the Tomcat container:
docker inspect 685e73f706f5 | grep -i port
            "PortBindings": {
                        "HostPort": "8080"
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
            "Ports": {},

Comment: Don't forget to link containers during `docker exec`.

Comment: ...and this is what I get from the MongoDB container:
docker inspect mongodb | grep -i port     
            "PortBindings": {
                        "HostPort": "27017"
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
            "Ports": {
                        "HostPort": "27017"

Comment: BTW is it Spring Boot app?

Comment: No, just SpringMVC. I'm interested in learning more about Spring Boot but we're mostly a React & SpringMVC shop here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143981/discussion-between-matt-moran-and-slava-semushin).